# looping in file_get_content php and output the content of each file with filename

Tags: php, loops, directory, file-get-contents, subdirectory

I m using this code to output content of files in a directory but I have two problems

first is that this directory contains sub-dir and this code doesn't output
 files content in these sub-dir

Second problem
I want this code to output like

Filename:"name of the file"
Content :"content of the file"
so that I can parse this

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('./Chemistry');
foreach($dir as $file)
{
  if(!$file->isDot() && $file->isFile() && strpos($file->getFilename(), '.md') !== false)
  {
     $content = file_get_contents($file->getPathname());
     echo $content
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct you want to output:

```
echo 'Filename: ' . $file->getFilename() . ' Content: ' . $content;
```

If this is not your intention I will require a more thorough explanation.

*** edit ***

For dir iteration use http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

From the top of my head **it goes a little something like this** (hit it)...

```
function loopDir($path) {
    $allFilesAndFoldersInCurrentFolder = scandir($path);

    foreach($allFilesAndFoldersInCurrentFolder as item) {
        if(is_dir($item)) {
            loopDir($path.'/'.$item);
        }
        else {
            echo 'Filename: ' . $file->getFilename() . ' Content: ' . $content;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solves my 2nd problem but my first problem is that 
i want it to loop over directory and sub dir in chemistry

Comment: How can I declare the path?
And store the above output in an object?

Comment: You are now talking about the absolute basics of PHP. I don't have time for that. 
Just know that the above code does exactly what you need.
Good luck!